# How MQTT Works behind the Firewall?

Tags: tcp, firewall, mqtt

MQTT work on TCP means it needs continuous connection, so how it works behind the firewall. is this keeps connection open all the time then how its safe for security purpose.

Comment: Why do you think keeping a connection open is a security risk? Also the term firewall in this context is very vague, please add more context.

Answer (score 4):

The MQTT client will open a persistent connection to the broker for the life time of the session.

Assuming the client is "behind" the firewall and the broker is "open" then this should work fine as long as the firewall allows outbound connections on port 1883.

Comment: Thanks @hardillb is there any way to use MQTT on port 80.

Comment: You should be able to configure most brokers to run on any port you want

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/users/504554/hardillb) Is this same same case with CoAP or it allow behind the firewall??